# Why did I get an ModuleNotFound error after I installed keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dqn

I did this to study `DQN`. I am sure I have installed `keras`, because when I type into the command prompt `pip install keras` all I get is `Requirement is Already Satisfied`.

**My code:**

```
from dqn_agent import DQNAgent
from tetris import Tetris
from datetime import datetime
from statistics import mean, median
import random
from logs import CustomTensorBoard
from tqdm import tqdm
```

**Getting error:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1d98c5613f54> in <module>
----> 1 from dqn_agent import DQNAgent
      2 from tetris import Tetris
      3 from datetime import datetime
      4 from statistics import mean, median
      5 import random

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dqn_agent'
```

Comment: Are you using the same python interpreter to run the code as the Executable that you used to install the package? Try using the same `python` command to install the package like `python3 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: now it says No module named 'keras' (sobs)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be trying to use **keras-rl**, not keras? If so, you will have to type `pip install keras-rl` in your terminal.

To import DQNAgent, you should modify `from dqn_agent import DQNAgent` to `from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent`.

For more information, check out the [keras-rl github](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl).

Comment: I tried to fix this error, and another error came up:from tensorflow import keras
from dqn_agent import DQNAgent
from tetris import Tetris
from datetime import datetime
from statistics import mean, median
import random
from logs import CustomTensorBoard
from tqdm import tqdm

Comment: <ipython-input-1-19ad70454b51> in <module>
      5 from statistics import mean, median
      6 import random
----> 7 from logs import CustomTensorBoard
      8 from tqdm import tqdm

~\DQNTETRIS\tetrisByQLearning-master\logs.py in <module>
      6 
      7 from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
----> 8 from tensorflow.summary import FileWriter
      9 
     10 class CustomTensorBoard(TensorBoard):

ImportError: cannot import name 'FileWriter' from 'tensorflow.summary' (C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\_tf\summary\__init__.py)

Comment: I don't know what to do :(

Comment: It looks like the above solved your DQNAgent error. This is a new error that popped up on line `from logs import CustomTensorBoard`. What version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: It's a 2.3.0 version.